# How can I print a multiple-digit decimal number stored in a register in LC-3 assembly?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have a program that should output a number in decimal notation. This is easy when there is only one digit, but I don't know how to handle the case where the number is greater than 10. I only need to print rational numbers.

Ive tried using the same instructions I would for printing a single-digit number (assume number to print is in R3, and there is an ascii offset in R6):

```
AND R0, R0, #0 ; clear R0
ADD R0, R0, R3 ; add R3
ADD R0, R0, R6 ; add ASCII offset
OUT
```

But this obviously doesn't work with numbers over 9.

Comment: Btw, you don't have to clear a register in order to copy the value from another register.  Take advantage of the 3-operand instructions, i.e. `ADD R0, R3, #0`, will copy the value without the need to clear first.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for ages but couldn't find the post you linked.